# Applying Autolayout on UILabels in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uilabel, ios-autolayout

I am trying to learn autolayout but stuck at a point.

This is what I want to achieve, i have a custom tableView cell in Which I have an imageView and 3 labels and a button.

[image]

I have tried to change their compression resistance priority and hugging priority but failed. So can someone please guide me how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you make your labels fixed size (numberOfLines != 0) they will automatically show ... if the text content does not fit.

To build your view layout, look at the new (as of iOS 9) UIStackView which allows stacking views and manages their auto layout.

One possible approach to your requirement is to have the three labels inside a UIStackView. Then use auto layout constraints to arrange the UIStackView, buttons and image. One of your constraints should make the UIStackView some fixed width and/or height so you can control the size of your labels:

Using visual language: H:[myStackView(==280)] or

```
theView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myStackView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, multiplier: 1, constant: 280))
```

Here's sample code for creating a UIStackView programmatically and the link to Apple's documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview

The sample code has two labels stacked horizontally, centered and of equal size, separated by 40. You will want to stack your labels vertically.

```
let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [negativeResponseButton, positiveResponseButton])
stackView.axis = .horizontal
stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
stackView.alignment = .center
stackView.spacing = 40
```